# Suggestions to evaluate this integral: $\int^{4b}_0 {e^{t(-a+2b -x)}\biggl(\frac{\sqrt{4bx-x^2}}{(2b-2c)^2+4cx}\biggr) dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate this integral which arises after analysing the linear segments of a key hole contour in the complex plane:

$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int^{4b}_0 {e^{t(-a+2b -x)}\biggl(\frac{\sqrt{4bx-x^2}}{(2b-2c)^2+4cx}\biggr) dx}$

Where $\ a, b, c $ and $\ t $ are positive constants

My current progress:

$\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{4b}_0 {e^{t(-a+2b -x)}\biggl(\frac{\sqrt{(2b)^2-(x-2b)^2}}{(2b-2c)^2+4cx}\biggr) dx}$

Using trigonometric substitution: $\ (x-2b) = 2b\sin z  $

$\frac{1}{\pi}\int{e^{t(\ -a-2b\sin z)}\biggl(\frac{4b^2\cos^2 z}{(2b-2c)^2 + 8bc\ +4c(2b\sin z)}\biggr) dz}$

Could someone please help me with some suggestions to continue?

Comment: What are the bounds? While possible it is unlikely such an antiderivative has a closed form, not to mention it should've come with bounds since it was part of a line integral.

Comment: Hi Ninad, thank you for you comment. I have added the bounds to the integral and edited the question.